# delimit into rows for every combination between two columns of unbalance elements with dplyr or data.table?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Hi suppose I have a dataframe as such,

```
df = data.frame ( 
  color = c("blue")
  ,sample = c( "A")
  ,size = c("L,S,XL")
  , sex = c ( "M,F") 
  )
 color sample   size sex
1  blue      A L,S,XL M,F
```

What I want ideally into  is to split by delimit size and sex into new rows.
so that the new dataframe would look like this.

```
  color sample size sex
1  blue      A    L   M
2  blue      A    L   F
3  blue      A    S   M
4  blue      A    S   F
5  blue      A   XL   M
6  blue      A   XL   F
```

I tried splitting it this way but it causing some errors.

```
df %>% tidyr::separate_rows(size, sex)  %>% data.frame()
```

Comment: base R option: `expand.grid(lapply(df, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, split = ","))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is due to the size and sex columns being `factors`. Convert these columns to strings using `as.character` and then your code should work. Note however, that the function does not allow different lengths in each column (ie. sex has 2 unique values, size has 3) so you have to do them one by one.

```
df$size <- as.character(df$size)
df$sex  <- as.character(df$sex)

(df.new <- df %>% tidyr::separate_rows(size) %>% tidyr::separate_rows(sex))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `separate_rows` function of `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate_rows(color,sep=",") %>%
      separate_rows(sample,sep=",") %>%
      separate_rows(size,sep=",") %>%
      separate_rows(sex,sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using the function `CJ` in `data.table` package or built-in function `expand.grid`:

#### using data.table

```
library(data.table)

do.call(CJ, sapply(df, strsplit, ","))

#    color sample size sex
# 1:  blue      A    L   F
# 2:  blue      A    L   M
# 3:  blue      A    S   F
# 4:  blue      A    S   M
# 5:  blue      A   XL   F
# 6:  blue      A   XL   M
```

#### using build-in function

```
expand.grid(sapply(df, strsplit, ","))

#   color sample size sex
# 1  blue      A    L   M
# 2  blue      A    S   M
# 3  blue      A   XL   M
# 4  blue      A    L   F
# 5  blue      A    S   F
# 6  blue      A   XL   F
```